# Generic Abstract Method

Tags: c#, generics, abstraction

I ran into trouble when trying to create an abstract class and a method in it that was generic in nature.

```
class GameRoomManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameRoom GetSomething(string s){
        //do things here
        return GameRoomvar;
    }
}
```

Now I have another class that does something similar, but different classes involved

```
class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour{
    public Player GetSomething(string s){
        //player related things here
        return Playervar;
    }
}
```

I want to have both classes GameRoomManager and PlayerManager inherit from an abstract class Abs

```
class GameRoomManager : Abs{
    public override GameRoom GetSomething<GameRoom>(string s){
        return GameRoomvar;
    }
}
```

where

```
public abstract class Abs{
    public T GetSomething<T>(string s);
}
```

I've seen a few answers on this topic when I was looking for solutions, and all suggested the abstract class itself be generic. I don't want to make the abstract class generic, since examples I saw would have me do `class GameRoomManager : Abs<GameRoomManager>`. But I want the method to return type GameRoom, not GameRoomManager.

I'm not totally familiar with generics, so please point me in the right direction if I'm going wrong

Comment: `But I want the method to return type PQR, not XYZ`  So then make `PQR` the generic argument.  Why does the generic argument need to be the type itself?

Comment: Yes, I have thought about this. But this example is just for one type of method which returns a T. Now what if I have another method which returns type U? I would have to make `GG<T, U>`, which seems pretty stupid to me. Might as well not make the abstract class at all, for that matter. Or is there another reason, or some better explanation why and how I should do it the way you're saying?

Comment: If you don't need an abstract class, then don't create an abstract class.  Given that it has no implemented methods, it really should be an interface, not an abstract class, but even then, if you don't need the interface, don't create one.  If you need one, then use it.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. As for the type parameters, I'm guessing no other way that to have `<T,U>` ?

Comment: The sample code is too vague to understand what you are really trying to accomplish here.  Not sure if it's an XY Problem or what.  It makes no sense to me to use generics in this way.  All you've accomplished is having two classes with a method that has the same name but behaves differently.  If HIJ and PQR inherited from a common base, then it would make more sense.  But then you'd also not need generics there.

Comment: Do you have anything in common between `PQR` and `HIJ`?

Comment: You could implement the interface twice, if that would make sense in context.  If it makes sense for you to want to have any object implementing two different methods, each with a different return type, then having an interface with two generic arguments could make sense, sure.

Comment: Hello Servy. I think your suggestion was more helpful. Could you post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have something in common with `PQR` and `HIJ` for the classes to use a common method.

**Plan A**

Connect things with interfaces.

```
public interface IPart
{
    // put things here that are common between Part and GameRoom
    int ID { get; }
}
public interface IAbs
{
    IPart GetSomething(string name);
}

public class GameRoom : IPart
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class GameRoomManager : IAbs
{
    GameRoom part;

    #region IAbs Members

    public GameRoom GetSomething(string name)
    {
        return part;
    }


    IPart IAbs.GetSomething(string name)
    {
        return GetSomething(name);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Player : IPart
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerManager : IAbs
{
    Player part;


    #region IAbs Members

    public Player GetSomething(string name)
    {
        return part;
    }
    IPart IAbs.GetSomething(string name)
    {
        return GetSomething(name);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Plan B**

Use a base class with a generic type & interfaces

```
public interface IItem
{
    // put things here that are common between Part and GameRoom
    int ID { get; }
}
public class GameRoom : IItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class Player : IItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}


public interface IAbs
{
    IItem GetItem(string guid);
}
public abstract class Abs<T> : IAbs
    where T : IItem
{
    protected abstract T GetItem(string name);

    protected Abs(T item)
    {
        this.Item=item;
    }
    protected T Item { get; private set; }

    #region IAbs Members

    IItem IAbs.GetItem(string name)
    {
        return GetItem(name);
    }

    #endregion
}


public class GameRoomManager : Abs<GameRoom>
{
    public GameRoomManager(GameRoom room) : base(room)
    {
    }
    protected override GameRoom GetItem(string guid)
    {
        return Item;
    }
    public GameRoom GetRoom(string guid) { return GetItem(guid); }
}

public class PlayerManager : Abs<Player>
{
    public PlayerManager(Player player)
        : base(player)
    {
    }
    protected override Player GetItem(string guid)
    {
        return Item;
    }
    public Player GetPlayer(string guid) { return GetItem(guid); }
}
```

here is some example usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<IAbs> managers=new List<IAbs>();
        var pm=new PlayerManager(new Player() { ID=1001 });
        var gm=new GameRoomManager(new GameRoom() { ID=2050 });

        managers.Add(pm);
        managers.Add(gm);

        IItem part = managers[0].GetItem("0000");

    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the question just about when you posted your answer. Added class names for you to make more sense of it

Comment: and I updated the answer. Please comment on how this approach might not meet your requirements because it is unclear to me what you are going after.

Comment: OK, so to be even more specific, the GetSomething will be GetRoom(string guid) which will return an object of GameRoom type, and same for player, it'll be GetPlayer(string guid) which returns a Player